# introduce a line break in a long equation

Tags: equations

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper,openright]{report}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[inner=3cm,outer=2cm,tmargin=2.0cm,bmargin=2.0cm, includefoot, includehead, headheight=15.8pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}



\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\label{equacao_silica}
\binom{\text{Quantidade}}{\text{Sílica (\% (w/w))}}
  = 100 - \left[\binom{\text{Perda de Massa}}{\text{(580\degree C-900\degree C)}
     \times \frac{100,1}{44}} - \binom{\text{Perda de Massa}}{\text{(30\degree C-200\degree C)}}
     -  \binom{\text{\% Resíduos}}{\text{GCC}} \right]\\
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

How I can introduce a line break in this equation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example (the presence of `-` at the end of line depends on typographic rules in your country):

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper,openright]{report}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunits} % added - PS
\usepackage[inner=3cm,outer=2cm,tmargin=2.0cm,bmargin=2.0cm, includefoot, includehead, headheight=15.8pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}



\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\label{equacao_silica}
\begin{aligned}
&\binom{\text{Quantidade}}{\text{Sílica (\% (w/w))}}
  = 100 - {}\\
&\qquad{} - \left[\binom{\text{Perda de Massa}}{\text{(580\degree C-900\degree C)}
     \times \frac{100,1}{44}} - \binom{\text{Perda de Massa}}{\text{(30\degree C-200\degree C)}}
     -  \binom{\text{\% Resíduos}}{\text{GCC}} \right]\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Probably some other environment, e.g. `gathered`, may be more suitable; `aligned` is only an example.

Comment: I have a problem with this code

Comment: @user46548 What a problem?

Comment: command \ohm already defined

Comment: @user46548 You have `\degree` in your code, hence I have assumed that the package `siunits` is missing. If not, comment that line and use your definition of `\degree`. There is no `\ohm` in your example.

Answer (score 1):

There are many possibilities for introducing a line break. A key step is *not* to use `\left` and `\right` to size the square brackets, since you can't have a line break across a `\left`-`\right` pair.

Here are two possible solutions, one using the `multline` environment, the other the `split` environment nested inside an `equation` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper,openright]{report}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[inner=3cm,outer=2cm,tmargin=2.0cm,bmargin=2.0cm, includefoot, includehead, headheight=15.8pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage{amsmath}  % is loaded automatically by 'mathtools'
\newcommand\degree{\ensuremath{^{\circ}}} %% correct this if necessary

\begin{document}
\begin{multline}
\label{equacao_silica}
\binom{\text{Quantidade}}{\text{Sílica (\% (w/w))}}
  = 100 - \biggl\{\binom{\text{Perda de Massa}}{\text{(580\degree C--900\degree C)}
     \times \frac{100,1}{44}} \\
- \binom{\text{Perda de Massa}}{\text{(30\degree C--200\degree C)}}
     -  \binom{\text{\% Resíduos}}{\text{GCC}} \biggr\}
\end{multline}

\begin{equation}\begin{split}
\label{equacao_silica}
\binom{\text{Quantidade}}{\text{Sílica (\% (w/w))}}
  &= 100 - \biggl\{\binom{\text{Perda de Massa}}{\text{(580\degree C--900\degree C)}
     \times \frac{100,1}{44}} \\
&\quad{}- \binom{\text{Perda de Massa}}{\text{(30\degree C--200\degree C)}}
     -  \binom{\text{\% Resíduos}}{\text{GCC}} \biggr\}
\end{split}\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

By the way, I think en-dashes (`--`) instead of single dashes should be used to indicate the temperature ranges.